# Send preview of webpage c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a aspx web page, that i want to send to customers(ex.receipts, or a confirmation of payment) via email.
I managed to extract the source code via streamreader but when i try to visualize the page via email it just show me a bunch of tags.

```
WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(path);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
```

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Sorry if I am misreading your question but you want to pull the html from a page and then send it in an email and display it like a web page. Then why not just use MailMessage class and make sure you set the BodyisHTML property to true. if you are unsure look up the MailMessage class from MSDN


  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is normal because, it is just a string. There is a project called [HtmlRenderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) in codeplex. You call look into that.

There is a fairly friendly documentation too. Think this is a good place to start [here](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Demo%20application&referringTitle=Documentation).